# Menu won't align properly

Tags: css, menu, superfish

I have a css menu and i need the children to align with the parent menu. I just can't seem to get this right. I've tried several things but the menu just won't center with the div.

How its supposed to look like:

[image: proper menu style]

Here's the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/V95wJ/

Comment: I know this is an example, but in your code when the menu comes down under agenda where would you like for the drop down to appear; all the way left? Or better yet what's wrong with Agenda's drop down? If you're talking about the Test being over to the left too far why not just pad it?

Comment: What browser do you use because for me it looks aligned, or i'm getting the question wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using

```
text-align:center;
```

for your parent menu, there is no way the children can be aligned with the parent with CSS. Maybe with js, but even with it, I don't think it's possible.

I think you'll have to do this by hand for each children menu.

Comment: Doing it by hand is not a possibility

Comment: Not for each children item. Just set the padding-left setting for each children again not item, but menu. I think the main categories won't change.

Comment: A simple resarch on padding would have given you the answer. But I'm too good : http://jsfiddle.net/V95wJ/3/ 
Look at the id's of the childs uls, and look at the end of the css.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ul.nice-menu li ul li a` style in the CSS could use some padding/margin adding to the left.
A quick test shows that setting the padding for this element to:

```
padding: 0;
padding-left: 20px;
```

...and adding

```
  margin-top: -10px;
```

to `ul.nice-menu li ul` makes the top and bottom of the menu and sub-menu touch neatly.

Should give roughly what you want.

Note, I tested in Chrome.

---

Edit: As pointed out by Jerska, your top menu items are centred, which means that aligning the text in the sub-menus won't work (at least not easily, and without much tweaking, and then probably it won't work for all browsers).

I'm leaving my answer tho', as it may help to point you in the right direction for, for example, left-aligned menu items.

Comment: Hey, the whole point is that the main a items should be positioned in the center. It's how the designer made it. Doing it for every child item is not possible as the client will be adding menu items.